# React Redux : is this.props limited?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react and redux.

I really don't understand this simple problem : i used this.prop to retrieve some data but the problem is this :

when i type :

```
console.log(this.props.activeDevice.device)
```

it returns the element i want that is to say :

```
Object { name: "InputTwo", deviceType: "Input", value: "21", description: "This is the second Input" }
```

then if i would like to retrieve the name value, i should type :

```
console.log(this.props.activeDevice.device.name)
```

but i get this error :

```
TypeError: this.props.activeDevice.device is undefined
```

[image]

whereas this.props.activeDevice.device is defined just above in the first console.log as you see.

Here the code where I use console log :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';


class DeviceConfig extends Component {

    render() {

        console.log(this.props.activeDevice.device); // this line returns me Object { name: "InputTwo", deviceType: "Input", value: "21", description: "This is the second Input" }

        // console.log(this.props.activeDevice.device.deviceType); // if I comment the first log and use this log, it returns me the error no matter if i target deviceType, name, value of the object

        switch(this.props.activeDevice.device.deviceType){

            case "Input":
                return (
                    <div>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td className="selected_DeviceName"> </td>
                                    <td> <input type="number" ref="inputConfig" defaultValue="" /> </td>
                                    <td className="sendButton"> Send </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>                  
                );

/////////////////////////////////////////
            default:
                return (
                    <p> Select a Device </p>
                );


        }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
            activeDevice:state.activeDevice,
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DeviceConfig);
```

activeDevice is linked to the action below :

```
 export const selectDevice = (device,index) => {
    console.log("Device Clicked : " + device.value + ":" + index);
    return {
        type: "DEVICE_SELECTED",
        payload: {device,index}
    }
};
```

But, if I use this payload :

```
payload: device
```

I can use for example this.props.activeDevice.name or this.props.activeDevice.deviceType. The problem could be the payload syntax ? I have in the first case 2 objects and one of these is a object, and in the second case i just have the object device.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure that in your first log, you don't get multiple prints? (and one of them is undefined, but still works).
I expect the second log gets fired before you actually have data in there

Comment: Yes, i get only one print :S

Comment: can you post the rest of the code where you log this?

Comment: So if you keep both the logs, one after the other, you get the first output and on the next line the error?

Comment: I'm more interested in how you populate the activeDevice object.

Comment: No indeed, i put a first console log where I type : this.props.activeDevice.device and then i replace this console log by this.props.activeDevice.device.name. It does not deal with two log in the same time

Comment: I put the code where the console log is

Comment: Can you use both logs together one after the other so we can make sure they are actually from the same moment? I am pretty sure you will first see the error, and not the object. 'device' is probably undefined at a point and prints nothing. After that you probably set a value for device in a reducer and the render method is called again when you actually see that object.

Comment: Can you also try wrapping the code you got in the render method in a 'if (this.props.activeDevice.device) {...} else {return (<p>Device not loaded</p>)}'

Comment: i put the two consol . log one after the other but i still have the error :S i can see my objec device by using console.log(this.props.activeDevice.device) but i can't use its properties such as this.props.activeDevice.device.name